# Some Glyphicons in Bootstrap not found

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, glyphicons

I'm trying to use Glyphicons in Bootstrap but I have this error:

```
> http://address/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
> http://address/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff  GET
> http://address/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't know what to do, I've tried all solutions proposed on StackOverflow.

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded them and copied them into the correct directory?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. In the www/fonts/ folder. And urls in the boostrap.css file are goods: "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"

Comment: does the css file have correct reference path?

Comment: If you downloaded bootstrap.zip and did not copy it into your folder in the same structure - the css file will be looking for it as if it were in the same folder structure. (my guess is that error is the css file looking for the fonts and not being able to find them because the folder structure is different)

Comment: The structure is exactly the same...

Comment: It's really tough to say without seeing how you are serving your files and the structure - because your issue is (obviously) the reference to the fonts is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add ttf|woff|woff2 in your .htaccess

RewriteRule !.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png|mp4|ttf|woff|woff2)$ index.php

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

find other

> glyphicon glyphicon-*

at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs

and make sure you included bootstrap css

Comment: I've tried with a lot of icons and bootstrap css is included.
"<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"  style="font-size: 75px;" ></span>" for example.
The big mistery is that some icons work like "envelope" and not others.

Comment: are you using a custom bootstrap or just including <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: should be no problem if you just include it